# Random Effects Model - Proc HPMIXED vs MIXED Dropped Intercept?

Tags: sas

We have a large dataset, and when we run proc mixed or `hpmixed` on a sample of the data, we get the same coefficients for the continuous variables. However, for `HPMIXED`, SAS ignores the reference values we give it for categorical variables, and the intercept becomes 0.

Is there an option to force `HPMIXED` to use an intercept and to 'not ignore' the ref="" values we choose?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This may be answerable without sample code (I don't know anything about HPMIXED so I don't know), but it would be a better question with sample code and a sample dataset (or write sample code based on `sashelp.heart` or similar).  It's possible for example that you are misspecifying the reference values.